# Show various nodes in different ways on home page in drupal7?

Tags: theming

I want to show nodes in different ways. For example, i want to show featured nodes, recent nodes. My question is that how we can show nodes in different ways on my home page.

See [this demo site](http://demo.wpzoom.com/manifesto), i want my home page in drupal as like it.the problem is that how to manage nodes different ways as posts in WordPress.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Drupal StackExchange !

You can build various views of same content using [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module in Drupal. You can follow this [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/673/where-is-a-detailed-tutorial-on-views) to know more about the views module and also Views Documentation in the project page.

Comment: link is not working dude